# Intersection observer do not set correctly at page load. Ok when scrolling

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I try to do a anchor menu which active element is set automatically depending of the section that is visible on the screen. I do it mainly to get more experience with Intersection observer API that I find really nice.

All work as expected, except one thing. When the page load, the active menu is set on the last element of the page(Contact) and not the first one visible(Home). But, when I scroll in the page and get at top, it is working correctly, the home section is set active when I am fully scrolled up.

I tried changing rootMargin a bit, it changed nothing. I even tried to do a dirty trick, scrolling up/down with JavaScript on page load, but even trigerring a scroll do not fix my issue.

Does someone have an idea of which part of my code is responsible of the bug? There the JavaScript I wrote for it :

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const header = document.querySelector('#site-header');
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
    const headerLinks = document.querySelectorAll('nav a');

    headerLinks.forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const targetId = e.target.getAttribute('href');
            const target = document.querySelector(targetId);
            target.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'start'});
        });
    });

    const options = {
        rootMargin: '0px 0px 75px 0px',
        threshold: 1.0
    };

    const onIntersect = (entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {

            const sectionID = entry.target.id;
            headerLinks.forEach(link => {
                link.classList.remove('active');
            });
            document.querySelector(`[href="#${sectionID}"]`).classList.add('active');
        })
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersect, options);

    sections.forEach((section) => {
        observer.observe(section);
    });
});
```

There a codepen with all code and visible bug: https://codepen.io/bdube/pen/ExeoGwO

Thanks for you time!

Benjamin